# In CSS, how to avoid accidentally getting a style from other classes, especially for widgets?

Tags: css

When we write our widgets using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS and package the widgets together as a library, we may have

```
.foobarwidget-sidebar-section .sub-section { border: 1px solid #000 }
```

so we will implement the JavaScript to work with the behavior of this widget that we defined, that can be used in any page on our website or by other people.

But then, if there is a user of this widget, and he has HTML in his own webpage for a "sub-section":

```
.sub-section { color: green }
```

Then pretty much his `.sub-section` will add to our widget's CSS style.

It is true that he can use

```
#the-main-content .sub-section { color: green }
```

or

```
.a-main-content-box .sub-section { color: green }
```

so that it doesn't affect our widget, but what if his design is that the `#main-content` box **contains** our `sidebar` widget (or a search box widget, or a social link button widget)?  In that case, his `.sub-section` will again affect our CSS for the widget.

Of course, we can define all the possible CSS styles for our widget, such as

```
.foobarwidget-sidebar-section .sub-section { color: blue !important;
                                             font-weight: bold !important;
                                            /* ... and all possible CSS styles ... */
                                           }
```

but that doesn't look like a good feasible solution.  We also might use

```
.foobarwidget-sidebar-section > .sub-section { ... }
```

so that the `.sub-section` must be the immediate child, but it doesn't affect a standalone `.sub-section` affect our widget's CSS.  In such situation, what is a good solution to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Disqus, which needs to handle this sort of thing, opted to solve their problem by putting their widget inside of an `iframe` where the parent's stylesheet won't affect it. I believe other popular widgety things do this too.

Comment: but we can't use an iframe for all widgets, such as if it is a simple social share button, or a super search box, then the whole page can have many iframes if the page use different types of widgets in the library many times

Comment: @動靜能量: You might have a lot of `iframe`s if you use this method, but it's not like it's impossible to have a lot of `iframe`s. I think you'd be surprised: most share buttons these days actually are `iframe`s, believe it or not.

Comment: I think it might be prevent scam as well, that the website owner can use some tricky JavaScript to trigger the "Share" button otherwise.  If iframe, then the same origin policy will prevent anything done to that Share button JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a less generic class for your widget something like `.my-custom-widget-name-sub-section`

Comment: yes, that's what I think too, that if it is a widget CSS, we really need to namespace our CSS `id` and `class` names

Answer (score 0):

You can put your css file last in the head, with jQuery:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourcss-last.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: being last doesn't alter the fact that it is affected

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an `id`. The CSS gods frown on IDs, but I think it's perfectly acceptable given the fact that you may or may not have control over the markup / user styles. This will reduce the chances of a user accidentally breaking your layout, while still allowing them to do so if they need it. For better or worse, i've seen this pattern in a lot of jQuery modules that are dealing with similar concerns.

It would also help to have more general "modular" class that describes the general functionality of `foobarwidget` and is not tied to a location like `.sidebar-section`.  From there, add the styles that make up `foobarwidget`. This will keep your css cleaner, and allow you to deploy `foobarwidget` to any area of the page without having to create an entirely new class name.

So,  `.foobarwidget-sidebar-section .sub-section { border: 1px solid #000 }` becomes:

```
#foobarwidget {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background:white;
}

#foobarwidget .subsection {
  /* this could probably be declared in #foobarwidget */
  color:black; /* one could use !important here, if absolutely necessary */
}
```

Comment: I think even with an `id`, it can still be affected.  The class that says some other styles can apply to the `.sub-section`

Comment: While it does open you up to potential conflicts, the specificity of the ``id`` would override any class declarations your user makes. You will just need to be more verbose in your css (declaring all the styles that you need like ``color``) otherwise a user will always be able to accidentally override your styles if they add a style to a containing element.